# Why does my toilet overflow when I turn the sink tap on?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, faucet, water-pressure

When I turn either this bathroom tap on, or another bathroom tap on, on the same floor, the toilet inlet starts letting in water. Please see this video:

https://youtu.be/GIuwzwYNUrQ

The valve was brand new when it started letting water in.

What's the cause, and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question good video!

The valve seat rubber may be worn so the slight pressure change causes it to flow, replacing that fill valve would only be ~10$ at home desperate even the specialty stores they are under 20$.

Since it seats when you lift it could have scale or rust sand in the valve spring cleaning it out could fix or replace as suggested above.

To clean or try turn the water off, pull the cap, put a cup or glass over the top, turn the water into let it flow, turn water reassemble valve and see if this cleared the problem.

Comment: FYI, I just replaced the float valve assembly in my toilet.  Cost $15 Canadian at the Blue Store, and took about 10 minutes (most of which was dealing with water).

Comment: Yikes a new valve, I have not seen this with this type of valve, is your water pressure below 40psi psi ?

Comment: I had another issue - But, it's as simple as draining the tank, disconnecting supply, unscrew plastic nut under tank, and then reverse the process with the new float assembly.  Dead easy.

Comment: I agree an easy job I keep one on the shelf and I am an electrician… I don’t think that is a pilot assisted valve but if it is and pressure below 40 may be the problem. I don’t know of many pressure switches below 40 and community water pressure is usually more also that’s why I asked if the pressure is below 40, if the internal is pilot assisted a low pressure will cause this.

Comment: Increasing the water pressure solved this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the fill valve will most likely work. Most modern fill valves use a diaphragm system similar to a sprinkler valve. These work by changing the pressure on top and bottom of the diaphragm. As the water rises the float connected to the little arm closes a small bleed hole. the pressure on top of the valve rises and closes the diaphragm. These valves are very sensitive to pressure variations. Like when you turn on a shower or such. When new they should be fine. but as the rubber ages they get less flexible, and the little stopper plug may not seal as well. So a new one will likely solve your problem. As an alternative you can still get the old style "ball and cock" valve. The one with the big float ball on the end of an arm.These don't use the diaphragm type valve, and so don't care about pressure variations. On the con side. They don't fill quite as fast and might be noisier.